# Page loads fast but page transitions slow

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using PHP with CodeIgniter 2.02 and MySQL for my site. When I click a navigation link to load another page on my site it takes a long time to load. I've run the CodeIgniter profiler and that shows that the pages in question only take 2 seconds to load including controller execution and queries. It's kind of like the web browser is just thinking for about 4 seconds and then decides to load my page. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could debug and pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Use firebug for firefox; in the net panel you'll be able to see what resources take how long. Maybe one resource is taking a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors which could be causing the slow speed:

- API's which are slow to respond to your requests
- Low browser memory
- Poor .htaccess or /config/routes routing
- High server load
- Poor use of cache or lack-thereof
- Poor use of conditional statements, loops, timeouts, `sleep()`'s etc.
- Too many included files
- Etc...

I'd run a unit test on the application and take advantage of [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) for optimization. It will point out bottlenecks and offer advice to speed up your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Using firebug with yslow I noticed that there were a number of improvements I needed to make with regards to the number of javascript and css files I was calling.  Using Minify and also better sizing a number of images sitewide my application is much snappier now.